# Is it possible to create a timestamp column which includes the meridian indicator in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm trying to create a column of type `TIMESTAMP` such that would store timestamps in the following format (i.e. including the "AM"/"PM" indicator):

```
20-04-2013 06:56:37 AM
```

I suppose I could use the `to_char(..)` function and store the timestamps as `TEXT` values, however isn't it possible to achieve the same effect with a vanilla `TIMESTAMP` column?

Comment: no. a timestamp is a timestamp. am/pm is a DISPLAY consideration. timestamps are stored using 24hr clocks. if hour>=12, then it's pm.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "create a timestamp column"? A timestamp (or date) column does **not** have any "format". Or are you trying to *convert* that value into a timestamp? If yes, what is the error you get?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to format a timestamp, use `to_char` when you `SELECT` it, or format the date in the client.

Timestamps don't have a format. They're stored as the number of fractional seconds since 1970-01-01 UTC inside the database and they're formatted into ISO timestamps for input and output. Inside the database they're just a number.

There is no way to override the default timestamp output format, since that would lead to a setting that could confuse applications that expect a single consistent format.

If the app wants a different date output format it has to ask for it with an appropriate `to_char` call.

Answer (score 1):

Is this roughly what you are looking for?

```
select to_char(now(), 'DD-MM-YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM')
```